# Draw mat from contour?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, math, contour

I use openCV to recognize contours. Now I want to create a new binary mat containing all coordinates of this contour.

[image: img]

1. Canny edge detection applied
2. found contour's (red one is the one I'd like to use)
3. just coordinates inside contour are drawn into new mat

---

**This is what I've got so far:**

```
vector<cv::Point> contour; // red marked contour;
cv::Rect boundingBox = cv::boundingRect(contour);

Mat newMat;
vector<cv::Point> insideContour;
for (int i=0; i<contour.size(); i++) {
    // get all coordinates inside of contour
    // insideContour.push_back(?)
}

for (int y=0; y<boundingBox.height; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<boundingBox.width; x++) {
       // newMat      
    }
}
```

Any help how to go on would be really appreciated because I'm absolutely clueless.

Comment: If it's ROI that you want, then simply use the bounding box to clip the image. The harder way: If the selected contour is non-rectangular, get binary image of the contour ( flood-fill should work ) and create  new mat by selectively deep copying from the original image using the binary image as keyer.

Comment: Would you mind to share some lines matching to your comment? @seccpur

Comment: @jonas00 Could you share the image after you applied Canny edge detection on its own?  It'd make helping you easier.  Also, the code you used to specifically find the contours for the image would also help.  That way it reduces how much tinkering I need to get the contours you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For simplicity cv::Point(250, 219) is a point inside the red contour, use Haar to find bounding box and it's center in reality.

```
cv::Mat image = imread("Smiley.jpg");
cv::Mat image2 = imread("Smiley2.jpg");

// subtract images and floodfill to prepare red mask 
Mat red_contour, red_mask, maskMat, outputMat;
subtract(image2, image, red_contour);   
threshold(red_contour, red_mask, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
int filling = cv::floodFill(red_mask, cv::Point(250, 219), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), (cv::Rect*)0, cv::Scalar(), cv::Scalar(), 4);

//prepare a grey mask
cv::cvtColor(red_mask, maskMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(maskMat, maskMat, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

// use mask to crop original image
image.copyTo(outputMat, maskMat);


cv::namedWindow("Image");
cv::imshow("Image", outputMat);

cv::waitKey();

return 0;
```